# Access sibling namespaces in Javascript, Change namespace variables in SEAF

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, namespaces, closures

I'm having trouble figuring out namespaces for a project.

My Namespace looks like this thus far:

```
var NS = NS || {};
NS.Utils = NS.Utils || {};
NS.Models = NS.Models || {};
NS.Views = NS.Views || {};

NS.App = (function () {

this.data = "hello";

var init = function () {

    alert(data);

};

return {

    data: this.data,
    init: init,

};

} ());
```

And then I initialize it with this:

```
(function ($, global, data) {

$(global).click(function() {

    NS.App.init();

});

NS.App.data = "hello testing";
NS.App.init();


}(jQuery, window, data));
```

But for some reason, the Second, NS.App.init() call does not use the updated NS.App.data variable. How can I fix this?

Also, how can I reference other namespaces inside of NS.App? For example, if I want to use NS.Utils inside of NS.App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `alert(data)` to `alert(this.data)`.

Comment: yeah, no idea, I would expect `undefined`